# Error when executing code in the same directory

Tags: java

I have this java files

```
ATestClass.java         DataStore.java      RequestsManager.java
ConnectionManager.java  ImportKeyPair.java  SSLClientTest.java
```

and this is how they look in a terminal

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc1-01:~/pdsl/src/pdslipay# ls
ATestClass.java         DataStore.java      RequestsManager.java
ConnectionManager.java  ImportKeyPair.java  SSLClientTest.java
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc1-01:~/pdsl/src/pdslipay# javac ATestClass.java
ATestClass.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                 RequestsManager req = new RequestsManager();
                 ^
  symbol:   class RequestsManager
  location: class ATestClass
ATestClass.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                 RequestsManager req = new RequestsManager();
                                           ^
  symbol:   class RequestsManager
  location: class ATestClass
2 errors
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc1-01:~/pdsl/src/pdslipay#
```

I am trying to run AtestClass.java but i get the error

```
ATestClass.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                 RequestsManager req = new RequestsManager();
                 ^
  symbol:   class RequestsManager
  location: class ATestClass
ATestClass.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                 RequestsManager req = new RequestsManager();
                                           ^
  symbol:   class RequestsManager
  location: class ATestClass
2 errors
```

I have the file `RequestsManager.java` in the same directory as ATestClass.java

ATestClass.java looks like this

```
package pdslipay;

public class ATestClass {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         RequestsManager req = new RequestsManager();

         try {
            req.payBillPrePaid("logan", "0", "saf", "000581");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
}
```

and RequestsManager.java looks like this

```
package pdslipay;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class RequestsManager {
....
}
```

I can't explain where the error is coming from given the two files are in the same directory.

Comment: Try manually importing RequestManager or try to compile RequestManager first.

Comment: Seems you are not compiled RequestManager.java

Comment: use `~/pdsl/src` as the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the files:

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc1-01:~/pdsl/src/pdslipay# javac *.java
```

then change to the root directory of your project, the one where the package structure starts, and use the package name when running the Class:

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc1-01:~/pdsl/src/pdslipay# cd ..
root@ubuntu-2gb-nyc1-01:~/pdsl/src# java pdslipay.ATestClass
```

(assuming you have not used an IDE or other tool that compiled the files into another directory structure like `~/pdsl/bin/`)

After compiling there should be *.class files in the directory "pdslipay". The compiler `javac` must be supplied with the *.java files to compile. The Virtual Machine `java` request the fully qualified class name that contains the main method ("pdslipay.ATestRequest"), not the *.class file. The Virtual Machine will search the class(es) in the directories listed in the CLASSPATH environment or given by the `-cp` option (defaults to".", the actual directory).